# Understanding Recruiter profile in detail

Tags: 7, distributions

I am trying to learn installation profiles. So i took up recruiter installation profile and trying to exploit it to learn.

I found the code like in the .profile file

```
<?php
// $Id: standard.profile,v 1.2 2010/07/22 16:16:42 dries Exp $

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Allows the profile to alter the site configuration form.
 */
function recruiter_form_install_configure_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  // Pre-populate the site name with the server name.
  $form['site_information']['site_name']['#default_value'] = t('eq-Recruiter');
}

/**
 * Implements of hook_install_tasks().
 */
function recruiter_install_tasks() {
  $tasks = array(
    'recruiter_import_vocabularies_batch' => array(
      'display_name' => st('Import terms'),
      'display' => TRUE,
      'type' => 'batch',
      'run' => INSTALL_TASK_RUN_IF_NOT_COMPLETED,
    ),
  );
  return $tasks;
}

/**
 * Defines batch op for importing
 */
function recruiter_import_vocabularies_batch() {
  $batch = array(
    'operations' => array(
      array('recruiter_import_vocabularies', array()),
    ),
    'finished' => 'recruiter_import_vocabularies_finished',
    'title' => t('Import terms'),
    'init_message' => t('Starting import.'),
    'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
    'error_message' => t('Example Batch has encountered an error.'),
  );
  return $batch;
}

/**
 * Import batch operation for vocs
 */
function recruiter_import_vocabularies(&$context) {
  if (!isset($context['sandbox']['progress'])) {
    $vocs = taxonomy_vocabulary_load_multiple(FALSE);
    $context['sandbox']['progress'] = 0;
    $context['sandbox']['current_node'] = 0;
    $context['sandbox']['max'] = count($vocs);
    $context['sandbox']['vocs'] = $vocs;
  }
```

Here i saw code like `$vocs = taxonomy_vocabulary_load_multiple(FALSE);`  He is just saying FALSE here. Does it now require any parameters? If no how is it fetching the values?

Comment: Any chance you could re-phrase the question a bit? It's a lot of text for a relatively short question. :)

Comment: @Letharion - you can edit my question. If you feel if not properly phrased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
taxonomy_vocabulary_load_multiple(FALSE)
```

will load *all* vocabularies. If you wanted a specific one you'd pass in the relevant id instead.